Is an asterisk needed when specifying a function pointer?
I can specify pointer to function in C code as follows:
double foo (double f (double), ... other parameters )

or
double foo (double (* f) (double), ... other parameters )

What is the difference?
Both methods works correctly.

Normally, the following declares a function:
void g( void )

And the following declares a pointer to a function:
void (*g)( void )

However, when declaring a parameter, they're equivalent. Both declare a pointer to a function.

C17 §6.7.6.3 ¶8 A declaration of a parameter as “function returning type” shall be adjusted to “pointer to function returning type”, as in 6.3.2.1.


Something similar happens for arrays.
Normally, the following declares an array:
char a[]

And the following declares a pointer to a char:
char *a

However, when declaring a parameter, they're equivalent. Both declare a pointer to a char.

C17 §6.7.6.3 ¶7 A declaration of a parameter as “array of type” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to type”, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

